# Was Shri Rama named by Maharishi Vashishtha?

Tags: ramayana, rama, vashishta

If so, was there any specific reason behind choosing that name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Shri Rama was named by Sage Vasistha:

Valmiki Ramayana Bal kanda

> अतीत्य एकादश आहम् तु नाम कर्म तथा अकरोत् |
>   ज्येष्ठम् रामम् महात्मानम् भरतम् कैकयी सुतम् ||१-१८-२१
>
> सौमित्रिम् लक्ष्मणम् इति शत्रुघ्नम् अपरम् तथा |
>   वसिष्ठः परम प्रीतो नामानि कुरुते तदा || १-१८-२२
>
> Elapsed are eleven days and the naming ceremony is performed, **then Vashishta, the chief priest, named the high-souled elder one as Rama,** Kaikeyi's son as Bharata, and one son of Sumitra as Lakshmana and the other as Shatrughna [1-18-21, 22]

The word 'Rama' is defined as

> **ramante sarve janaaH guNaiH asmin iti raamaH '** 
>   in whom all the people take delight for his virtuousness, thus he is Rama.'

Hanuman in Ram Rahasya Upanishad tells that in the word "राम" . "रा" is taken from Ashtakshari mantra " ॐ नमो नारायणाय " and "म" is taken from Panchakshari mantra "नमः शिवाय" ।

> The true meaning of the king among the Rama mantras, as well as of the **eight-lettered
>   Narayana and five-lettered Shiva mantras**, is spoken of as thus:
>   
>   Where yogi-s revel in the 2 syllable mantra viz. ‘Ra ma’ where the ra syllable denotes fire
>   
>   wherein abides illumination. Its nature as Existence-Consciousness-Bliss is regarded as the supreme meaning, the
>   
>   consonant denoting the unchanging Brahman, and the syllable the energy of
>   
>   manifestation.
>   
>   Know that Consonants joined to Syllables are used in breathing; the sound ‘r’, of the
>   
>   nature of light, is therefore used in action.
>   
>   The sound ‘ma’, is known as ‘maya’ indicating prosperity; being itself the seed-letter
>   
>   (bijakshara) is also equal to Brahman itself.

Comment: Nice, I found this shloka and its meaning rather beautiful: "ramante sarve janaaH guNaiH asmin iti raamaH "

Comment: @Amit Saxena where is this sloka exactly..?

Comment: In the definition of the word? You might not call it a Shloka exactly, though.

Comment: @Amit Saxena yes, it actually is derived by applying Vedanga principle called Nirukta...

Comment: Just like 'poornaat jayate iti puja' :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many meanings of ram naam

**रमन्ते योगिनो यस्मिन सः रामः।**

Upon whom Yogis meditate and gets delighted ie ram

**राशब्दो विश्ववचनो मश्चापि ईश्वर वाचकः।
विश्वानाम् ईश्वरो योहि तेन् राम प्रकीर्तितः।।**

ब्रह्मवैवर्तपुराण तथा नारद पंचरात्र अन्तर्गत जयाख्य संहिता

The word Ra denotes the world and the word Ma denotes God. The one who is the God of the universe, that is why he is called Ram

रा शब्द विश्व का और म शब्द ईश्वर का वाचक है। जो समष्टि का ईश्वर है, इस कारण से वह राम कहा जाता है।

**रा चेति लक्ष्मी वचनो मश्चापि ईश्वर वाचकः।
लक्ष्मीपतिं गतिं रामं प्रवदन्ति मनीषिणः।।**

ब्रह्मवैवर्तपुराण तथा नारद पंचरात्र अन्तर्गत जयाख्य संहिता

The word Ra represents Lakshmi and the word Ma represents God. That is why the sages call Lakshmipati, the shelter of all, as Ram.

रा शब्द लक्ष्मी और म शब्द ईश्वर का वाचक है। इसीलिए मनीषि सब के आश्रय लक्ष्मीपति को राम कहते हैं।

**रमाया रमणः साक्षात् तेन रामेति कीर्तितः।
स ते तनयतां प्राप्तः पुर्ण ब्रह्म सनातनः।।**

आदि रामायण ७१.२२

He was directly called by Ram who was the beloved of Rāma. That eternal Brahman has attained to your sonship.

**रमणाद् इति रामः।**

Anand ramayan

One who gives delight to others is called as Ram

And there are many more meaning in addition to that. Many scriptures gave different types of meanings to ram naam. Eg brahmayamal tantra, rudrayamal tantra, shakti sangam tantra etc